# 142^23%187 modulo RSA should be 65 but is 53 any idea why?

Tags: c#, math, encryption, rsa, modulo

As in title, 142^23%187 should be 65 not 53.
It is part of RSA encrypting/decrypting algorithm.

Previous modulo operation is correct but secon one is not.

If u type 142^23%187 in wolphram alpha is correct 65 - and 65 is indeed A after decrypting.

Any ideas?
Code below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace RSA
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");



            AlgoritmRSA RSA = new AlgoritmRSA(11, 17, 7);
            RSA.Encrypting("A");
            RSA.Decrypting();



        }
    }
}

namespace RSA
{
    public class AlgoritmRSA
    {

        public AlgoritmRSA(int p, int q, int e) 
        {
            this.P = p;
            this.Q = q;
            this.E = e;

        }
        public int P { get; private set; }
        public int Q { get; private set; }
        public int E { get; private set; }

        List<int> J = new List<int>();
        List<double> C = new List<double>();
        List<double> NJ = new List<double>();
        List<char> ASCIIList = new List<char>();

        public void Encrypting(string message)
        {
            int n = P * Q;
            System.Console.WriteLine("N = {0}",n);

            foreach (var item in message)
            {
                J.Add(Convert.ToInt32(item));
            }

            System.Console.WriteLine("E = {0}", E);

            foreach (var item in J)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("J = {0}", item);
                C.Add(Math.Pow(item, E) % n);
                System.Console.WriteLine("C = {0}", C[0]);
            }

        }


        public void Decrypting()
        {
            double CC = Math.Pow(142, 23);
            double BB = CC % 187;
            System.Console.WriteLine(CC);


            int n  = P * Q;

            int K = ((P-1)*(Q-1)+1)/E;
            System.Console.WriteLine("K = {0}", K);


            foreach (var enc in C)
            {
                NJ.Add(Math.Pow(enc, K) % n);
                System.Console.WriteLine("NJ = {0}", NJ[0]);
            }

            foreach (var item in NJ)
            {
                ASCIIList.Add(Convert.ToChar(item));

            }

            System.Console.WriteLine("Encrypted Message: \n");

            foreach (var item in ASCIIList)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("{0}", item);
            }


        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You use ind and double - this will not work for your numbers! Use BigInteger or BigDecimal instead.

Comment: Interesting... PowerShell is reporting the same thing:  [math]::Pow(142, 23) % 187 = 53

Comment: Even making it a BigInt via explicit casting didn't fix it:   ([bigint]([math]::Pow(142, 23))) % 187 = 53

Comment: @thepip3r You should cast before `Pow`, and you should not use `[Math]::Pow`, but `[bigint]::Pow` or better `[bigint]::ModPow(142, 23, 187)`.

Comment: Yeah was just writing that up.  Thx

Comment: When I use System.Numerics.BigInteger.ModPow() everything is fine and answer is correct (which I expect) - it means 65. Thanks for all help You provide me!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you are in PowerShell, works out to 65, as intended.

```
[bigint]::Pow(142, 23) % 187
```

...worrisome that the normal math function doesn't report an error and just reports incorrect information.

Comment: There is no error, [Math.Pow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.pow?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Math_Pow_System_Double_System_Double_) converts its arguments to double and returns a double. Since 142^23 is *way, way* too big to be exactly represented as a double you get the best double approximation which works out to 31814999504641998300455543523595688200117378088960.

Comment: So the math comes out wrong due to limitations in a programming function and that's not a problem?  I may be misunderstanding but if I get an answer, without an error, I think most assume it has provided the correct answer.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your correct answer using bigint, but your lament that Math.pow "just reports incorrect information" is misplaced. It's up to the programmer to understand the limits of floating point arithmetic. See the classic [is floating point math broken](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/238704)

Comment: Guys, thanks for all that time You spend on answers, all of them are helpfull for me! I'm not experienced programmer, I'm just lerning it.